# How to add an array of images in ios which should change on button click?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, nsarray, ibaction

In my app, I have an image view and two buttons, I want to create an array of images, when the app is started, the first image should be displayed, then when the buttons are pressed, the next image or previous image should be displayed(in run time) in the image view.
[image]

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I have used [animateImageView startAnimating];

Comment: But, with this, we can change the image after a corresponding time, but I want to change them after each button click

Comment: Can I know, Y this question is put on hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage* image;
image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",name]];
[array addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",name], nil]];
```

Comment: k, then how to display them

Comment: @chandru is it in a different button action you should display them?

Comment: havent u seen the above diagram, the arrows are the buttons

Comment: inside button action retrieve corresponding objectatindex

Comment: Ya, but if the image at index 1 is present in the image, then the button action should contain the image at index 2, then after that it should change to index3, then index 4, till 5, as I am going to use only 5 images, vice versa for the "previous button"

Comment: It should chnage dynamically

Comment: declare a variable whose value gets incremented each time it enters the button action..so each time when it enter the btn action objectatindex should also change.

Comment: can U get me a sample code

Comment: i don't have a mac system right now to try it out.. try yourself from what all i told.

Comment: if you have found this useful in someway please do up vote..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Collection View with paging enabled or a custom image carousel. Check some libraries on Github and see what suits better your needs.

Comment: I cant wat u r actually telling

Answer (score 0):

Try to use QuickLook Framework and read articles for it. This is provided by apple itself rather than using the other framework. Also you can try using pageviewController.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html

You can also view images from it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep list of images in an Array. initially you will display image at index[0], when you tap on next increment index value by +1 and for previous decrement by -1. this will fix it.

Comment: Actually, I know wat U r saying, but how to implement it, and how to change the value after each click